# PyVisa JPEG Screen write ":MMEM:STOR:JPG"

Tags: python, pyvisa

I try to do some actions with a spectral analyzer Agilent.
Open and close connexion is ok, same for classics commands as Trace, Frequency...

I have problem with the backup or a screenshot. In Python i fail to do that
my code line : inst.write(":MMEM:STOR:JPG 'C:\ScreenDate.JPG''"), i tried many syntax, with the f", I have tried everything but nothing works.

I have some "errors" on analyzer like " -350 Queue Overflow" so i don't know where is the problem...

I work with pyvisa

Thank You

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Is it `MMEM:STOR:JPG` or `MMEM:STOR:SCR` which gives a `*.png`? Which model do you have?